# Android Display Selected Table Row in Dialog

Tags: android

I'm trying to display table row in dialog box when it clicked . The rows contains images. Is that possible to view in dialog ?

When I run this code below it shows an error in LogCat say's "You must call removeView() on the child's parent first".

and the error is on this line -> " alertDialog2.setView(tr); "

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);      
       TableLayout tbl_add = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);


        int tr_size = tbl_add.getChildCount();
        for(int ctr = 0; ctr < tr_size; ctr ++){
        final TableRow tr = (TableRow)tbl_add.getChildAt(ctr);

            int td_size = tr.getChildCount();
                for(int inner_ctr = 0; inner_ctr < td_size; inner_ctr++){
                    tr.getChildAt(inner_ctr).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialog2.setView(tr);
        alertDialog2.show();
    }
    });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before setting a view in a new parent you need to remove it from current parent view as below

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
//(tr.getParent()).removeView(tr)
((ViewGroup)tr.getParent()).removeView(tr);
alertDialog2.setView(tr);
alertDialog2.show();
```

Then it will work

Comment: it shows an error in eclipse @Rajen Raiyarela :( The method removeView(TableRow) is undefined for the type ViewParent

Comment: see my answer i commented one line and added a new line instead of that.